# Refer to Tab to Right

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to help make a manual commission process go faster. I ran into an issue with one of the formulas in the process when creating the macro.

To give more context, a report is run with one tab labelled "Data" with all the sales transactions. The retail team keeps a separate Excel file to house all transactions from the past year in order to help filter returns that are older than 2 weeks. They copy the ISO sheet to the main report and use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(S2<0,VLOOKUP(P2&0,'ISO History 2.3'!U:V,2,0),0),0)
```

In the VBA code, it looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(RC[-2]<0,VLOOKUP(RC[-5]&0,'ISO History 2.3'!C:C[1],2,0),0),0)
```

The ISO tab name is always changed with the most recent date of transactions they have. When I created the macro, it recorded the current name of the ISO tab. Is there a different way to refer to the sheet? It's always placed after the "Data" tab, so I was wondering if there's a way to refer to the next tab in the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheets have a `Next` and a `Previous` property.  If there's no "next" or "previous" sheet then these properties return `Nothing`.

Worth noting though that (eg) `Next` will happily return a Chart sheet if that's the next one to the right, so depending on your use case it might be worth adding in a check for that.

Answer (score 1):

- `Index` property returns the index number of the sheet object.
- `Sheets(Sht.Index + 1).Name` get the next (right) sheet's name

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Worksheet.Index property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.index?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm174078)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim sSht As String, sFormula As String
    Set Sht = Sheets("Data")
    ' Check if Sht is the last one
    If Sht.Index < Sheets.Count Then
        sSht = Sheets(Sht.Index + 1).Name
        sFormula = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[-2]<0,VLOOKUP(RC[-5]&0,'" & sSht & "'!C:C[1],2,0),0),0)"
        ' Your code to apply formula
        ' ..
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also: `Worksheet.Next`

Comment: @TimWilliams It's way better than my answer. Pls post it.